# Why using current loop control in speed control of DC motor

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, power-electronics, dc-motor, motor-controller

As far as I read about speed control of a DC motor, I have come out with the following statements:

- Speed control of a DC motor can be acheived by controlling armature voltage of that DC motor and this comes frome the steady state equation of equivalent electrical circuit of a DC motor:
  W=Va/Ke -(Ra/Ke^2)*TL.
  (W:rotational speed, Va:armature voltage; Ke:electromotive coefficient and TL:load torque).
- The control loop of the speed control system is composed of two main loops:

2.1 The current loop: an inner current loop to control the armature current.

2.2 The speed loop: an outer loop to control the speed of the motor is used to generate a **reference current** that is injected to the inner current loop.

**The questions that rises to my mind, are :**

- What is the real advantage of having a speed loop cascaded to a current loop?
- How the two loops are combined and linked to generate the control voltage?
- What is the mathematical relationship between speed error, and the reference current?

As far as I understood, the two loops should be built as follows:

**Right now don't focus on the values of the circuit or the type of Opamp**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUmuZR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is no one in this community section to answer or comment on my question? or give a starting hint? Specially how to loops are linked in hardware (Circuit)??